# Joomla 2.5: Adding a custom image parameter to an article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I want to be able to add an image next to the title of an article (and be able to select the image for each article - not just a one and done setting).  I modified the /administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml file by adding these fields at the top of the  section:

```
<field
     name="titleImage"
     type="media"
     label="Title Image"
     description="Image that will be displayed next to the article's title." />
<field
     name="spacer0"
     type="spacer"
     hr="true"
/>
```

This adds the parameter to the Edit Article page and lets me select an image.

I added this code to my theme's com_content/article/default.php page (inside the if ($params->get('show_title')) block):

```
<?php if($this->params->get('titleImage')){ ?>
<img class="titleImage" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->titleImage); ?>" alt="Title Image" />
<?php } ?>
```

The image is not appearing on the page.  I'm new to Joomla so it may be obvious, but what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: At the end of the day, what I am doing here works - once I add one small character.  For some reason the computer can't tell that when I type this: $this->params-> , I obviously mean this: $this->$params->  Sometimes I hate programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.5 there is already a standardized image field (actually 2) and all you have to really do is make a layout override to put the images where you want them.

YOu should modify the form using a plugin if you go that route. I would modify the image field to add a third image if you are already using the two of hem.

Comment: I'll agree that this is probably the best answer for accomplishing the stated goal.  But part of what I'm trying to do is to really get under the hood of Joomla to see what I can do.

Comment: Ok but actually overrides are one of the really great features of Joomla. If you understand them then a lot of other pieces will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out why it wasn't working:

Firstly, you need to ensure you add the field to a specific place in **article.xml**. I would suggest adding it before or after `<field name="show_title">` on line 127

Then, you can call the parameter like so:

```
<?php if ($params->get('titleImage')) : ?>
    <img class="titleImage" src="<?php echo JURI::root() . $params->get('titleImage'); ?>" alt="Title Image" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps